# Where can I find the Google Assistant "Use screen context" on/off switch?

Tags: android-12, google-assistant

Despite this:

[image]

https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7393909?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid

this Samsung does not show this on/off switch. Instead, "Use screen context" is a button which goes to a page of switches, none of which have this label.

So, where can I find the "Use screen context" on/off switch?

Comment: Please add more details about the phone and android version. Also are you looking at the right place?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot on the question? I have Samsung Galaxy M12 on Android 13 (also Google Pixel 3a on Android 12), and following the above procedure shows the expected option (whether it's working or not on a Samsung device is a different matter)

Comment: Am I looking in the right place? I doubt it. But I sure am looking in the documented place.

Comment: Andrew, could you post a screenshot showing where it is prresent? All I could post is where it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Within the assistant settings, the **Use screen context** option takes you to a settings page titled **Digital assistant app**. If you disable the *Use text from screen* toggle, this will have the effect you're looking for, and you'll notice the two following toggles are disabled to show the entire feature has been turned off.

Example:

[image: Use screen context enabled]
[image: Use screen context disabled]

Comment: I dont think this answers the question. Anyway lets wait for him to reply

Comment: "the Use screen context option takes you to a settings page titled Digital assistant app". Not here. It takes me to "Device assiistance app" which is unlisted on Settings > Apps.

Comment: "If you disable the Use text from screen toggle" I get nobsuch toggle (on/off switch).

Comment: Thanks for the suggested alternative but note this does not answer the question.

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot showing what you're describing when you navigate to these options? This was the answer to the question on my Pixel 6 Pro, but may need to be expanded to include options for your Samsung device.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/I5VmZt9.png

Comment: Perfect! These are the same options, just with different titles. This would indicate that your "Use screen context" setting is currently on.